# Auto re-assign ids in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id': [542588, 542594, 542594, 542605, 542605, 542605, 542630, 542630],
 'label': [3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

      id   label
0   542588  3
1   542594  3
2   542594  1
3   542605  1
4   542605  2
5   542605  0
6   542630  0
7   542630  2
```

The `id` columns contains large integers (6-digits). I want a way to simplify it, starting from `10`,  so that `542588` becomes `10`, `542594` becomes `11`, etc...

Required output:

```
    id label
0   10  3
1   11  3
2   11  1
3   12  1
4   12  2
5   12  0
6   13  0
7   13  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `factorize`:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].factorize()[0] + 10
```

Output:

```
   id  label
0  10      3
1  11      3
2  11      1
3  12      1
4  12      2
5  12      0
6  13      0
7  13      2
```

**Note**: `factorize` will enumerate the keys in the order that they occur in your data, while `groupby().ngroup()` solution will enumerate the key in the increasing order. You can mimic the increasing order with `factorize` by sorting the data first. Or you can replicate the data order with `groupby()` by passing `sort=False` to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```py
df['id'] = df.groupby('id').ngroup().add(10)
```

```
print(df)

   id  label
0  10      3
1  11      3
2  11      1
3  12      1
4  12      2
5  12      0
6  13      0
7  13      2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a naive way of looping through the IDs, and every time you encounter an ID you haven't seen before, associate it in a dictionary with a new ID (starting at 10, incrementing by 1 each time).

You can then swap out the values of the ID column using the `map` method.

```
new_ids = dict()
new_id = 10

for old_id in df['id']:
    if old_id not in new_ids:
        new_ids[old_id] = new_id
        new_id += 1

df['id'] = df['id'].map(new_ids)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?